# Which scenario of Javascript closure is preferred?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, closures, counter

In what scenario would the counter1 be preferable? In what scenario would counter 2 be better?

I understand when declaring a variable globally can be unpredictable but is there a scenario this will be preferred over declaring it inside the function?

```
// counter1 code
function counterMaker() {
  let count = 0;
  return function counter() {
    return count++;
  };
}


// counter2 code
let count = 10;

function counter2() {
  return count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare the `count` variable in the outer scope if you want it to be referencable elsewhere, without having to increment the count:

```js
let count = 10;

function counter2() {
  return count++;
}


counter2();
counter2();
console.log(count);
```

If the `count` variable is inside a closure, and the closure only exposes the returned function, the above isn't possible - the only option is to call the returned function which will increment count even if you only want to check its current value.

The first method where `count` is only viewable by the `counter` function in the closure would be useful if you want to make it clear to consumers of `counterMaker` and to readers of the code that the `count` variable is *intended* to be private (and completely inaccessible outside).

The first method will also work when you want to create *multiple instances* of a counter, whereas the second method won't (unless  you repeat a counter variable and function every time you want a counter, which is silly).

Answer (score 1):

> Explanation for counter 1 code.

```
// counter1 code
function counterMaker() {
  let count = 0;
  return function counter() {
    return count++;
  };
}
```

Here you returning a function to the caller. So could do something like this at the caller.

```
var c = counterMaker()
c() //0
c() //1
c() //1
var b = counterMaker()
b() //0
b() //1
b() //1
```

because you tried enclosing that function and the variable environment when you tried used function expression. So your increment function is not exposed outside. If this makes sense, then you would understand the whole brevity about why closure and where closure.

> Explaination for code 2

```
// counter2 code
let count = 10;

function counter2() {
  return count++;
}
```

You are trying to expose the increment function into global and now you won't be able to create multiple instances like above as code 1. So every time the function counter2 will get called, it would just increment whatsover.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in this case, access to the variable through closure is more preferable than access to the external variable. Access to the external variable creates side-effects, your function becomes dependent on changes that occur outside of it, and they can be unpredictable. Or, in the future, you will want to move this function, you will still need to monitor this external variable. I think that all external dependencies should be passed to functions through parameters.